# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

Estou a fazer uns testes com cliente/servidor onde o cliente está a ser desenvolvido com angularjs e o servidor java + tomcat + jersey.

Quando tento fazer um post do lado do cliente, o mesmo chega ao servidor ao local certo mas a resposta é que não chega. Na consola do browser dá o erro que está no título.

O código que tenho é o seguinte

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/Arq/xml/AuthorService/login',
  data: login,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log('success');
  $scope.app = response.data;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  $scope.app = response;
});
```

e no servidor

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response doLogin() {
  System.out.println("REST API");
  UserModel p1 = new UserModel();
  p1.setEmail("aa@qq.pt");
  p1.setMobile_number(123);
  p1.setName("TESTE");


  return Response.status(200)
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*')
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With")
    .entity(p1)
    .build();
}
```

A parte estranha é que se eu utilizar o POSTMAN tudo corre bem. Se tentar através da página que estou a desenvolver, dá erro.

Alguém sabe como resolver? Preferia não usar nenhum plugin para desactivar o CORS mas sim uma maneira através de código (supostamente era através do header Access-Control-Allow-Origin mas não dá totalmente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema adicionando isto ao web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```